# Twitter Bootstrap 2.1 modal is removing modal-body contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a strange bug when trying to implement a simple modal in Twitter Bootstrap 2.1: the modal window appears as it should, everything seems perfect for a split second, and then the contents of the `.modal-body` div disappears. When I look at the HTML, it's there for a second and then is actually removed, containing `p` tag and all, leaving just an empty

```
<div class="modal-body"> </div>
```

Here's my code for the modal toggle button and the modal window:

```
<a type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#modal_confirm_delete" data-toggle="modal">Delete</a>

<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal_confirm_delete">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>Modal title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body. This stuff is getting removed for some reason</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel!</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Continue...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Incidentally, I've tried removing the fade class from the modal, based on some other comments I've read. The exact same bug occurred, albeit without the nice effects.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle for this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [the plugin code](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.1.1/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L227), if you have an `href` set, that doesn't contain a `#`, it will assume the [`remote` option](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) is set.

You can override this default action by setting the option explicitly like this :

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/robots.txt" data-remote="false" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#modal_confirm_delete" type="button">Delete</a>
```

[Working demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7EXhs/3/) - re-run to use each button if you want to see the differences

I guess you just didn't include the full url in your paste, if not, check any JS that is used to activate the modal or to bind on any events.

Comment: I'll try that when I'm back on my work computer with the code, but I don't think that's it. The modal was toggling fine and appearing with no problem, it was just hiding the modal-body contents. I know the body was there because it appeared for a second, and was then removed.

Comment: @BenjaminHarris If the page to where the url is pointing is empty (or something that [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) would consider empty), the content would be visible while the remote page is asynchronously loaded

Comment: I just tried it. That was it! I didn't even think about that, even though I vaguely remember reading about that property on the documentation. Thanks very much!